# Possible to copy directory of local packages into qemubuilder?

Tags: qemu, pbuilder

I am looking at isolating my pbuilder scripts a bit further, it does explicitly say it does not support bindmounts. But is it possible to not bindmount but copy an entire directory into the image during building instead?